# Binomial series from the composition of the series for $e^x$ and $a\ln(1+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to show that if one substitutes $$y = a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n} = a\ln(1+x)\tag1$$ for $|x| < 1$ with $a,x \in \mathbb{R}$,
inside the series $e^y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}$  $(2)$, the binomial series $$(1+x)^a = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{a}{n}x^n$$ is obtained?

First I want to recall that such an operation (followed by a rearrangement by powers of $x$) is certainly allowed by the main rearrangement theorem and because $(2)$ is everywhere convergent, while $(1)$ is absolutely convergent for $|x| < 1$.

After the substitution the new series obtained is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-+\ldots)^n}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^k$$

and we are looking at the final coefficients $c_k$ of $x^k$. For example if $k=2$, we see that we have one term from $n=1$ which is $-a/2$ and one more term from $n=2$ which is $a^2/2!$: thus the sum is $c_2 = a^2/2!-a/2 = a(a-1)/2 = \binom{a}{2}$. Is it possible to use induction? How can we derive the general formula for $c_k = \binom{a}{k}$?

**note:** I'm aware of other techniques to show the validity of the binomial series, I'm just wondering if it can be done in this way.

Comment: It's possible, but this way (basically) goes through [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Generating_functions).

Comment: So basically, it boils down to prove that $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}S(n, k) = \frac1{k!}(z-\frac{z^2}{2}+-\ldots)^k$$?

Comment: I would like to see such an approach though...